# how to build shoes and ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: c, ruby, build, shoes

I have been trying to build shoes with ruby 1.9.3, and get the following errors at the end of the build:

```
main.c:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `ruby_snprintf'
main.c:(.text+0xcb): undefined reference to `ruby_run_node'
dist/libshoes.so: undefined reference to `ruby_vsnprintf'
dist/libshoes.so: undefined reference to `rb_str_new_cstr'
dist/libshoes.so: undefined reference to `rb_intern2'
```

This is on a Fedora 15 box.

After much googling, I found the following comment:

"Now I remember where I saw those error messages building Shoes! It was when I compiled Ruby from source without the help of RVM or apt-get (yum for you). The Ruby makefile makes choices that Shoes and it's rake file don't like."

I tried re-installing ruby 1.9.3 with rvn, but no luck.  Also, I tried building ruby 1.9.3 from source, and looking in defines.h etc. to see if I could get some insight on how to do a build that sets things up so that shoes will build.  Also no luck.

Does anyone know how to get shoes to build?  Is there some way to configure and build ruby 1.9.3 so that shoes will build?  Do I have to hack up the shoes source code?  Is there some documentation on building ruby that explains how to build 1.9.3 so that the above five references are defined?  I notice that the source file vsnprintf.c is not getting compiled when I build ruby.  Is that file needed for ruby_snprintf?  If so, how do I configure the ruby build process to compile it?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [Green Shoes](https://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes).

The one you try to install is the original Shoes and it has some native C component. Green Shoes is purely Ruby, there are no C dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I did some google searches and I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/shoes/shoes/issues/113#issuecomment-1542590), I hope it helps: